# Use value of select option as name for a variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables, d3.js, html-select

I have a select form with different options. I want to get the value of the option that is selected when it changes. The value has the same name of a variable that put in a function.

So I want to put the value of the selected option into my function as a variable. How should I do this?

This is my select form:

```html
<select class="select">
    <option value="value1">option 1</option>
    <option value="value2">option 2</option>
    <option value="value3">option 3</option>
</select>
```

This is my JavaScript:

```
var value1 = ['item1', 'item2', "item3", ...]

$(".select").change(function () {
    $(".select option:selected").each(function() {
        var dataset = $(this).val();            

        d3.select(".chart")
            .selectAll("div")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of flooding your global scope, use an object to hold the possible combinations. reference the object with the value.

```
var dataPoints = {
    value1 : ['item1', 'item2', "item3", ...],
    value2 : ['item1', 'item2', "item3", ...]
};

$(".select").change(function (){
    $(".select option:selected").each(function(){

          var dataset = $(this).val();          

              d3.select(".chart")
               .selectAll("div")
               .data(dataPoints[dataset])
               .enter();
    });
});
```